# Click inside iframe using Actions (Selenium)

Tags: c#, selenium, iframe

I want to click at a point inside an iframe using Actions class of `Selenium`. But the code I'm trying is not clicking. Below is the code:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveByOffset(x-coordinate, y-coordinate).Click().Perform();
```

I also tried passing the driver like:

```
Actions action=new Actions(driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0));
```

But it was giving error and I couldn't find any other way to pass the driver with a frame selected.
The error I'm getting is

> Unable to locate frame 0

Comment: please insert error message. Can yo interact with the iframe after switching the iframe?

Comment: I have added the error message

Answer (score 0):

You couldnt switch to iframe, better way is to assign an iframe object the swithc to it. You need to find the iframe by xpath:

```
IWebElement iframe =  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//html//body//iframe"));
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iframe);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveByOffset(x-coordinate, y-coordinate);
action.Click();
action.Perform();
```

Comment: It didn't click on the points, but I didn't get the unable to locate the frame error.

Comment: @SidharthJain I think you can switch to iframe but not clicking the coordinate. Check it?

Comment: @SidharthJain calling `.click()` and `.perform` at the same time is not working. Check the updated code ?